# Remove format string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string format:

```
(header1:content1(note1, note2),content2(note3),content3)-(header2:content)-(header3)
```

Now I want to remove all contents, expected output I want is

```
(header1)-(header2)-(header3)
```

How can I do that? I tried some regex but output is incorrect.

**Update 1:**
`header`, `content` and `note` can contain any character but `(` and `)`.

**Update 2:**
@adsmith resolve my original problem. Now my string format like this:

```
normalcontent1-(header1:content1(note1, note2),content2(note3),content3)-(header2:content)-normalcontent2-(header3)
```

Expected output:

```
normalcontent1-(header1)-(header2)-normalcontent2-(header3)
```

Comment: Can you give us a quick sample of what the data actually looks like? If `header`, `content`, or `note` can contain `(` `)` `:` or `,`, it could really mess with someone's solution.

Comment: And the `pro forma` question: what have you tried so far? Specifically, show us your code.

Comment: If your header, content, and note can contain any character then this is impossible to format reliably via regex. There's no known delimiters.

Comment: @adsmith: I updated my question again.

Comment: Okay that's something I might be able to work with.

Comment: `I tried some regex but output is incorrect.` -- Do you mind _revealing_ what you tried?

Comment: @devnull: Yes. Some regex I made work in some cases and fail in some cases.

Comment: @Pacman Your updated question will require a parser, it's not regular language so a regular expression can't parse it. If you can GUARANTEE that you'll never see anything like `normalcontent1-(header:content)-normalcontent2-normalcontent3-(header2:content2)` then it might be doable but we're getting pretty deep here.... Parsing is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getheaders(text):
    elements = re.split("(?<=\))-",text)
    return '-'.join(["("+header.split(":")[0].strip("()")+")" for header in elements])

text = "(header1:content1(note1, note2),content2(note3),content3)-(header2:content)-(header3)"
getheaders(text)
>>> '(header1)-(header2)-(header3)'
```

Please note that this WILL fail if `header` contains a `:`, so you may want to parse those cases by hand if they appear incorrect. I don't have a great solution if I can't delimit the header from the content, sorry. If the CONTENT couldn't have `:` you could just do `split(":")[:-2]` but if both header and content can contain a `:` then it's impossible to tell (programattically) where the header ends and the content begins.

Comment: I updated my question again. Can you help me?

Comment: @Pacman if you change the `re.split("(?<=\))-",text)` to `re.split("(?<=\))-|-(?=\()",text)`, it will grab your `normalcontent` fields as requested, but it will wrap them in parentheses like the headers so they may be difficult to tell apart. Not sure if that's better or worse, but there you are :). Again, this is ASSUMING that no two `normalcontent` fields will be adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com):

```
import pyparsing as pp
import re

txt='''normalcontent1-(header1:content1(note1, note2),content2(note3),content3)-(header2:content)-normalcontent2-(header3)
normalcontent1-(header:content)-normalcontent2-normalcontent3-(header2:content2‌​)'''

def DashSplit(txt):
    ''' Replicate the function of str.split(',') but do not split on nested expressions or in quoted strings'''
    com_lok=[]
    dash = pp.Suppress('-')
    # note the location of each dash outside an ignored expression:
    dash.setParseAction(lambda s, lok, toks: com_lok.append(lok))
    ident = pp.Word(pp.alphas+"_", pp.alphanums+"_")  # python, C type identifier
    exp=(pp.nestedExpr())                             # Ignore everthing inside nested '( )'

    atom = ident | exp 
    expr = pp.OneOrMore(atom) + pp.ZeroOrMore(dash  + atom )
    try:
        result=expr.parseString(txt)
    except pp.ParseException as e:
        print('nope', e)
        return [txt]
    else:    
        return [txt[st:end] for st,end in zip([0]+[e+1 for e in com_lok],com_lok+[len(txt)])]      

def headerGetter(txt):
    m=re.match(r'\((\w+)', txt)
    if m:
        return '('+re.match(r'\((\w+)', txt).group(1)+')' 
    else:
        return txt    

for line in txt.splitlines():    
    print('-'.join(headerGetter(e) for e in DashSplit(line)))
```

Prints:

```
normalcontent1-(header1)-(header2)-normalcontent2-(header3)
normalcontent1-(header)-normalcontent2-normalcontent3-(header2)
```

If you correctly define your grammar, a parser will be a far more robust solution than a regex.